# pythonanywhere - How do I use websockets to transmit messages as per the web2py messaging example?

Tags: websocket, web2py, pythonanywhere

So I've built out an app to test websockets with web2py and pythonanywhere and I got it to work locally but when uploading to pythonanywhere it doesn't work. I think the reason is that I'm sending things to localhost (127.0.0.1) but have no idea where I need to send things (and listen to) when uploading.

the debug.py script is:

```
def listen():

    script=SCRIPT('''
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           var callback=function(e){$("#test_div").html(e.data)};
    if(!web2py_websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8880/realtime/mygroup',callback))
             alert("html5 websocket not supported by your browser, try Google Chrome");
         });
     ''')
     d = ''
     return { 'd':d , 'script':script }

def send():
    form=LOAD('debug','ajax_form',ajax=True)
    return { 'form':form }

def ajax_form():
    form=SQLFORM.factory(Field('message'))
    if form.accepts(request,session):
        import websocket_messaging
        reload( websocket_messaging )
        websocket_messaging.websocket_send( 'http://127.0.0.1:8880' , form.vars.message , 'mykey' , 'mygroup' )                                                                    
    return form
```

the listen.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<div id="test_div">
    {{=d}}
</div>

{{=script}}
```

the send.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{=form}}
```

**A few more points:**

- I start the tornado server as per [this](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py) from a bash terminal in pythonanywhere.

  ```
  python websocket_messaging.py -p 8880 -k mykey
  ```
- I've got a free account on pythonanywhere and would like to test this out before I start paying for one.
- I found [this](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/Using%20Tornado) which seems to imply I can't do what I want on pythonanywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here -- unfortunately WebSockets don't work on our service at the moment :-(

Comment: I was afraid this might be the answer. Any plans for having this work in the near future?

Comment: It's definitely on the to-do list, but we don't have an ETA.  I've added an upvote to our task tracker FWIW.

Comment: @evan54 any updates ? is it supported now ?